# Simple query return the same register

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a problem with the return of a simple query

**Table San_ChaveBematech**

```
ID     Chave_Id     Credenciada_Id    Recibo   Impresso
55     571678       10                Test     0
```

**Table San_CadastraBematech**

```
ID     Maquina          Credenciada
5      000FEAB63D89     10
6      003067D6A4E7     10
7      003067D6A4D4     10
```

**Query That I has some problem**

```
SELECT San_ChaveBematech.Recibo
FROM San_ChaveBematech
JOIN San_CadastraBematech
ON San_ChaveBematech.Credenciada_Id = San_CadastraBematech.Credenciada
WHERE San_ChaveBematech.Credenciada_Id = 
       (SELECT top 1 credenciada 
        FROM San_CadastraBematech 
        WHERE maquina = '000FEAB63D89')
AND San_ChaveBematech.Impresso = 0
```

**How It Works**

I have an application (Windows Form) where my user will be registered. I'll save her register in my `San_CadastraBematech` table. In my web application I can get some keys and, when I get it, I'll save the data in `San_ChaveBematech` table. To print it, I do the query that I put here, but look, I have just one register in `San_ChaveBematech` but my query return the same register 3 times.

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: because it has three matches on table `Table San_CadastraBematech`. what do you really want to print?

Comment: Top 1 without an order by may return different results at different time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT top 1 Ch.Recibo
  FROM San_ChaveBematech Ch
  JOIN San_CadastraBematech Ca
    ON Ch.Credenciada_Id = Ca.Credenciada
 WHERE Ca.maquina = '000FEAB63D89'
   AND Ch.Impresso = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your subquery

```
SELECT top 1 credenciada 
        FROM San_CadastraBematech 
        WHERE maquina = '000FEAB63D89'
```

will return the value 10; this is matched in 3 records in the San_ChaveBematech.Credenciada_Id column.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Top 1 San_ChaveBematech.Recibo
FROM San_ChaveBematech
JOIN San_CadastraBematech
ON San_ChaveBematech.Credenciada_Id = San_CadastraBematech.Credenciada
WHERE San_CadastraBematech.maquina = '000FEAB63D89'
    AND San_ChaveBematech.Impresso = 0
Order By San_CadastraBematech.ID Desc
```